# C# Non-invocable member 'ProdhimiQumështit.DataTabel' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, methods, c#-4.0

Recently, I tried to fill with info from another forms to this form the combobox automation.But it say that this method cant be used .
How can i do it ?

```
 private void FillLopId()
        {
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select LopId from LopTabel",Con);
            SqlDataReader Rdr;
            Rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = DataTabel();
            dt.Columns.Add("LopId", typeof(int));
            dt.Load(Rdr);
            LopaIdCb.ValueMember = "LopId";
            LopaIdCb.DataSource = dt;
            Con.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change line `DataTable dt = DataTabel();` to `DataTable dt = new DataTabel();`

You are trying to create a new instance of a class. To do that, you need to use the `new` operator. `DataTable` is a class so you can't call it like it's a method.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: If there is a method called DataTabel, which returns an instance of DataTabel, it could be valid.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is not correct
DataTable dt = DataTabel();

There is no class named DataTabel,
Instead it should be
DataTable dt = new DataTable();